I habe Problem with function "excute" in Cplex
Could you please tell me, where is wrong
int Preferenz [1..b*c*d] = ...;
int H[1..b][1..c][1..d]; // Preferenz der Dozenten für Zeitperiode

execute{  
  var count=0  
  for (var j in 1..b){    
    for (var k in 1..c){      
      for (var l in 1..d){        
        count=count + 1;        
        H[j][k][l]=Preferenz[count];
      };
    };
  };  
};


I ran the configuration, but H wasn't shown. I think I might have made a mistake with the "count".

You should not use .. for a range in the scripting part of OPL, only in the modeling part.
For example
int b=2;
range r=1..b;

execute
{
writeln("step 1");
for (var j in 1..b) write(j);
writeln();
writeln("step 2");
for (var j in r ) write(j);
writeln();
writeln("step 3");
for (var j=1;j<=b;j++) write(j);
writeln();

}

gives
step 1

step 2
12
step 3
12


Hi Alex, thanks for your help. The code is run.
